# iOS Auto Layout - How to have two stacked views in portrait move to side by side in landscape?

Tags: alignment, autolayout, uiinterfaceorientation, stacked

I am updating my app and want to allow landscape orientation.
I am wondering how I can take two views that are stacked on top of each other (and centered horizontally in container) while in portrait and move them to be side by side in landscape (and centered vertically in container).

I would like the bobblehead to be aligned on the left, and the quote box to be aligned on the right. Both views should take up full height while in landscape.

Here are some screen grabs:
[image: Portrait Mode]
[image: Landscape Mode]

Comment: This tutorial doing exactly what you want, http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial

Comment: If you still have problem send me current project i will edit it in few minitues.

Comment: @Jageen - That did the trick! I didn't realize you could select constraints to only be applied to certain layouts (i.e. Any Width x Compact Height, etc.). Can you copy that comment into an Answer so I can accept it and give you credit? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you want is having different layout when device size is not fit to your view.**
In iOS8 you can do it without hard coding it.
Yes just by designing right constraint for right size class([introduce in XCode6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014509-SW15))

Here is an example which doing same as you want
**[Example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)**

**Code**
[Download project](http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/AdaptiveWeather.zip)

**Output**
[image]
[image]